# How to perform action in child component if a button in parent route is clicked

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular4-router

I am working with angular 4. I have parent and child routes in my application.

In parent, I have 2 buttons -> 'Add' & 'Remove'.

I want to call a function of my child component when 'Add'  button is clicked in the parent route. I have no idea how to implement this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it child tag inside the parent, or is child behind a router-outlet?

Comment: Its behind the router outlet.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the template variables for this.

```
// child.component.ts
@Component({ selector: 'child', template: '...' })
export class ChildComponent {
    public someFunctionToCall() {...}
}

// parent.component.html
<div>
   <child #childComponentRef></child>

   <button (click)="childComponentRef.someFunctionToCall()">Add</button>
</div>
```